# Finding iterative intersection of array elements Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, intersection

I want to find common elements in  Arrays listed in a  hash (Hash of arrays) in iterative manner and then divide each "intersection" by scalar value of first array. Iteration of intersection with other arrays for each array.

```
my @CS1= ("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "-c5");
my @CS2= ("c1", "c2", "c8", "c9");
my @CS3= ("c1", "c2", "c3");


my %CSHash= ( "set1" => [@CS1],
         "set2"=> [@CS2], 
         "set3" => [@CS3],

        );
```

My proposed Solution: But, it does not generate desired out put.

```
  my %union=();
  my %isect=();

my $cumLativeIsect=0;

 foreach my $lst(keys %CSHash)
 {
   my $elCount=0;

    foreach my $ele(@{$CSHash{$lst}})
   {
    $elCount++;
    $union{$ele}++ && $isect{$ele}++;
    }

   my @intrsection= keys %isect;

if($elCount!=0 && scalar @intrsection!=0 )
{
 $cumLativeIsect+=  scalar @intrsection/$elCount;
}

}
```

Mathemetically, I am loking for following computation ( intr=intersection):
Intrsection=|{(cs1 intr cs1)/cs1+ (cs1 intr cs2)/cs1+ (cs1 intr cs3)/cs1}|+|{(cs2 intr cs2)/cs2+ (cs2 intr cs1)/cs2+ (cs2 intr cs3)/cs2}|+|{(cs3 intr cs1)/cs1+ (cs3 intr cs2)/cs1+ (cs3 intr cs3)/cs3}|

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to even attempt to solve the problem. It is just some data structure definitions. Please show the code that you're having trouble with, and explain what problems you're having and what your question is. The requirement to achieve this  *“without using pre-defined function in Perl”* is very strange. Is this homework?

Comment: @Borodin Are you sure, my code is not visible to you? I have arrays(CS1, CS2 ) containing strings and they are then listed into hash. All I need is to process that hash arrays to find out iterative intersection of arrays with each other.

Comment: That's not code, because it doesn't actually do anything. You've made no attempt to actually solve the problem, which is making this look like a 'do my homework for me' request.

Comment: And *"without using pre-defined function in Perl"* is also a very homework-like restriction. It's impossible to write a useful Perl program without using a pre-defined function

Comment: @Borodin I agree that my questions should be more pragmatic and ask for any scientific or technical help. However, I am pretty new to "Perl", and, processing the data structures incur lot of complex loop formation. I definitely had to consult "Stack Overflow". For convenience of readers, I have changed my question now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry, I am a little bit confused. What is actually the meaning (described in plain english) of `(cs1 intr cs1)/cs1` ? According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), the backslash is "set difference" operator.

Comment: ... but the forwards slash is not defined?

Comment: @HåkonHægland  It is intersection of cs1 set and cs2 set and then dividivsion by cs1. Sorry for inconvenient text, couldn't find better way to put.

Comment: Why intersection with `c2` ? When it says `cs1 intr cs1`? And what do you mean by "division by `cs1`"? Did you mean `|cs1|`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Point is, I need to implement this data structure to collect some dependency information in analysis work. Although, this is test code, while I have different data to work with.Of course, the division is with scalar of CS1. i.e, |CS1|.

Comment: ok sorry I am not so familiar with set theory.. then to check my understanding, you want to compute: `|{(cs1 ∩ cs1)/|cs1| ∪ (cs1 ∩ cs2)/|cs1| ∪ (cs1 ∩ cs3)/|cs1|}| + |{(cs2 ∩ cs1)/|cs2| ∪ (cs2 ∩ cs2)/|cs2| ∪ (cs2 ∩ cs3)/|cs2|}| + ... ` . Is this correct?

Comment: Problem with the last interpretation is the meaning of `(cs1 ∩ cs1)/|cs1|`. Since the set `cs1` is not numeric ( it seems to consist of strings like `"c1"` ) it does not make sense to divide each element by `|cs1|`.. Maybe you meant: `|(cs1 ∩ cs1)|/|cs1|` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Can we have email correspondence, as this one is related to research task. I got to know from your profile that you are researcher as well.

Comment: Also, you understood it correct now.

Comment: Of course, we should limit this discussion here. Just send me an email and we can clarify things more easily.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Can I have your email ID ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was in the profile. Here it is: `hakon.hagland@gmail.com`

Comment: Check inbox @HåkonHægland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. I have renamed some of your variables, and used an array of array instead of a hash of arrays. After our discussion in the comments, I assumed you wanted to compute the following:

```
   {|cs1 ∩ cs1|/|cs1| + |cs1 ∩ cs2|/|cs1| + |cs1 ∩ cs3|/|cs1| + ... } 
 + {|cs2 ∩ cs1|/|cs2| + |cs2 ∩ cs2|/|cs2| + |cs2 ∩ cs3|/|cs2| + ... } 
 + ...
```

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(any);

my @sets = (
    [ "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "-c5"],
    [ "c1", "c2", "c8", "c9"],
    [ "c1", "c2", "c3"],
    [ "c1", "c2", "c3"],
    [ ],
    [ ],
);

my $intr_sect = 0;
for my $set1 ( @sets ) {
    my $N = scalar @$set1;
    for my $set2 ( @sets ) {
        my @intersect;
        for my $item ( @$set2 ) {
            if ( any { $_ eq $item } @$set1 ) {
                push @intersect, $item;
            }
        }
        $intr_sect += (scalar @intersect) / $N if $N;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Hakon! But, I need slightly different computation. Can you look at the solution, I have proposed and then give me any hint to solve this complex computation.